# Custom page template in every custom post type page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a page called "page1" and the url is "mypage.com/page1". This page have some sub-pages and I need create a sub-page called "sub-page1" with the url "page1/sub-page1".

If I create a normal page, it doesn't allow to insert in the url the character "/" so can't create the url and sub-page that I need.

I thought in create a Custom Post Type called "page1" so every page of this will has the url "mypage.com/page1/name_of_page", but I need to create a individual template por every page created in this Custom Post Type.

How can I create a Custom Template page for each page created in a Custom Post Type ??

Any Idea..

Comment: look here: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-content-in-wordpress-with-posts-and-pages--cms-27090 and this one: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: you just can create as many pages/templates as you want, and can add parent and child as you need. Then you'll not need to find something magical. just use features, which provided from wordrpess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create normal page and set parent on the right site.
Normal page = page1
parent site will be page1/parent-site

[select parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnqnf.png)

if you want to use a custom post type, you can hook
custom things to single.php

```
function my_custom_single($single) {

global $wp_query, $post;

/* Checks for single template by post type */
if ( $post->post_type == 'POST TYPE NAME' ) {
// do stuff here
}
return $single;
}
add_filter('single_template', 'my_custom_single');
```